# Poblema con llave foránea nula, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

estoy haciendo una consulta con Entity Framework:

```
   * //Tengo 2 entidades.

      public class Actividades
      {
            public Actividades()
            {
               this.ActividadesDependientes = new HashSet<Actividades>();
               this.Bitacora = new HashSet<Bitacora>();
            }

        public long idActividad { get; set; }
        public long? idActividadPredecesora { get; set; }
        public long? idProyecto { get; set; }
        public string desActividad { get; set; }
        public DateTime? fechaInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime? fechaFin { get; set; }
        public Decimal duracion { get; set; }
        public string actividad { get; set; }

        public DateTime fechaRegistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public long idUsuarioActualiza { get; set; }
        public long idUsuarioRegistra { get; set; }

        public virtual Proyectos Proyectos{ get; set; }
        public virtual Actividades ActividadPredecesora { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Actividades> ActividadesDependientes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Bitacora> Bitacora { get; set; }

    }




 public class Proyectos
    {
        public  Proyectos()
        {
            this.Actividades = new HashSet<Actividades>();
        }

        public long idProyecto { get; set; }
        public string claveProyecto { get; set; }
        public string nombreProyecto  { get; set; }
        public string descProyecto { get; set; }
        public Decimal duracion { get; set; }  

        public DateTime fechaRegistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public long idUsuarioActualiza { get; set; }
        public long idUsuarioRegistra { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Actividades> Actividades { get; set; }
    }
```

Dentro de mi clase AdminProyectosContext

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Actividades>()
   .HasKey(c => new { c.idActividad });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Proyectos>()
   .HasKey(c => new { c.idProyecto });


    modelBuilder.Entity<Actividades>()
   .HasRequired(p => p.Proyectos)
    .WithMany(c => c.Actividades)
   .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.idProyecto });
```

Esta ultima consulta,es la que me da problemas, porque al realizar el acceso 
ala propieddad nombreProyecto `(  X.Proyectos.nombreProyecto  )`, no puede acceder porque mi propiedad idProyecto
es un campo nulleable, tal caso provoca que los registros que tenga idProyecto como null no los esta devolviendo.

Esto es comprensible, ya que el campo idProyecto, es una llave foranea que al 
no tener valor no puede vincularse con la entidad Proyectos.

En mi clase ProyectosController, tengo esto.

```
public ActionResult ConsultarActividadesPorProyecto(long[] Proyectos)
        {
            var db = new AdminProyectosContext();
            var nomActividad = db.Actividades.AsQueryable();
            long idProyeto = Proyectos[0];

            if(idProyeto != 0)
            {
              nomActividad = nomActividad.Where(x => x.idProyecto == idProyeto);
            } 

            nomActividad = nomActividad.OrderBy(x => x.actividad); //.ThenBy(x => x.fechaActualizacion);

            var valor = nomActividad.Select(X => new   {
                                                X.idActividad,
                                                X.idActividadPredecesora,
                                                X.idProyecto,
                                                X.desActividad,
                                                X.fechaInicio,
                                                X.fechaFin,
                                                X.duracion,
                                                X.actividad,
                                                X.fechaRegistro,
                                                X.fechaActualizacion,
                                                X.idUsuarioActualiza,
                                                X.idUsuarioRegistra,
                                                X.Proyectos.nombreProyecto 
                                      }
               );

            return new JsonNetResult(new { JSONOArrayProyectos = valor });
        }
```

Lo que he intentado, es ponerle un simbolo de null, para cuando la propiedad Proyectos sea nula, aun siga mandando ese registro

```
 X.Proyectos?.nombreProyecto
```

Me da el siguiente error
"Una expresion lambda, de arbol de expresion no puede contener un 
operador de propagacion NULL", he intentado otras cosas, pero como
ando de novato en esto, no he podido corregirlo, Agradeceria que alguien
me explicara, un poco

Comment: ese lenguaje es C#?

Comment: si, @RuslanLópez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el campo permite nulos deberias usar el `HasOptional()` en luga del `HasRequired()`

[API de Fluent: relaciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships)

Ademas recomendaria que a las clases las definas con singular igual que las propiedades cuando no son coleccion

```
 public class Actividad
 {
    //otras propiedades

   public virtual Proyecto Proyecto{ get; set; }
 }
```

quedando

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Actividad>()
             .HasOptional(p => p.Proyecto)
             .WithMany(c => c.Actividades)
             .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.idProyecto });
```

Comment: Vaya funciono, muchisimas gracias ... mirare la lectura que me paso